# Should Multi module Java projects have Multiple Gradle Project

Tags: java, gradle, module, structure

I'm starting to get into java modularity and I am wondering if a multi-module project should be split into sub-Gradle projects. If this is or isn't the case, what would the directory structure look like? I've seen some conflicting examples of structures for non-Gradle projects such as:

```
reverse/dns/module/module-info.java 
                ./packages..
reverse/dns/module/module-info.java 
                ./packages..
```

and

```
reverse.dns.module/
            module-info.java // module-info is in the root directory and its name corresponds to parent folder
            reverse/dns/module/packages..
```

Would it look something like this?

Really I would just like to know how to structure a Gradle project if I were to have two modules. I intend to use jlink also to create images if that conflicts with anything.

Comment: doesn't that depend on the fact if you want to share some module vs it matters only within the project that you have set-up? In our code-base these modules are not supposed to be shared, so we only have a single `module-info.java`...

Comment: JUnit 5 uses modules extensively and is built with Gradle. I suggest looking over their repo for ideas/guidance: https://github.com/junit-team/junit5

Comment: @Eugene I intend to have them as separate modules since one of the modules can exist completely separately without the need of the second module. Because of this I thought it best to modularize the entire application. It also makes a lot of organizational sense and allows me to restrict access to classes if others try and use the first module. I'm starting to think having two subprojects might suffice but it'd be good to know how to work with multiple modules in gradle for the future.

Comment: @Francisco Mateo wow looking at it is a big help thanks! They put their module-info in its own directory which is a curve ball to me, haven't seen that so I'll have to look into it.

Comment: @FranciscoMateo this is not a fair comparison. As far as I understand from [this commit](https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/pull/1848/commits/f8ed9ad6c37bfcf9512f2747874d3974750b9d16) this is needed to be able to turn plain jars to modules at any point in time, without making them Automatic-Modules. I doubt this is ever the case for the OP.

Comment: @joshpetit _I intend to have them as separate modules_ then you have no question. Otherwise, if you want to share and encapsulate - the choice is obvious. What I meant with "our code" - we have a separate code base from every micro-service and they _do_ use shared code sometimes, but that shared code is made from a single gradle module. So I guess, it's easier for us?

Comment: @Eugene Ok makes sense, for your codebase, the needed shared code was in a single gradle module. I try not to worry about the structure too much (although I do sometimes over worry haha) so I've pretty much decided to make it into two subprojects and if in the future I see something more suited for my use case I'll try and restructure it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked a variation of this question:

> I'm using gradle and the jlink plugin and have an application that I want to split into two modules, are the modules supposed to be under the src/main/java directory or should it be refactored to src/mod1/ and src/mod2? Another question that comes from this is testing and where to place junit test classes. I'm mostly wondering about the directory structure of all of this. Thanks!

to [Nick Maiorano](https://www.linkedin.com/in/nickmaioran/?originalSubdomain=ca) and received this response:

> For your first question, the Java compiler and runtime have no opinion on this. They support either types of directory structures. But Java editors like Intellij and Eclipse kind of force you into having separate source roots for each module. If you plan on having different teams maintaining their own modules, then you'll have to have seperate roots and you would use their modules just like a 3rd party library with module dependencies through a jar or jmod file. Otherwise you could have different modules under a single source but you'd be fighting against Eclipse's/Intellij's module support (but it is possible).

> Your second question is much easier: unit test classes should be in the same module as their test subjects. They should have access to every class in the module so it makes sense that they be part of the module. They should be in a separate directory but the same package name as their test subjects (so that they're not blocked from accessing package private methods).

This fits the way I decided to architect the application by having two separate Gradle sub-projects, each of them having their own src/main/java directory. My final directory structure looks like this:

```
wit-core/
├── build.gradle
├── core.vim
└── src
    ├── main
    │   └── java
    │       ├── dev
    │       │   └── joshpetit
    │       │       └── wit
    │       │           └── core
    │       │               ├── base
    │       │               ├── interpret
    │       │               └── model
    │       └── module-info.java
    └── test
        └── java
            └── dev
                └── joshpetit
                    └── wit
                        └── core
                            ├── base
                            └── utils
wit-gui/
├── build.gradle
├── Session.vim
└── src
    ├── main
    │   └── java
    │       ├── dev
    │       │   └── joshpetit
    │       │       └── wit
    │       │           └── gui
    │       │               └── launcher
    │       └── module-info.java
    └── test
        └── java
            └── dev
                └── joshpetit
                    └── wit
                        └── gui
                            └── launcer
```

Lots of thanks to the people who parsed this question through with me!

If anyone else is still wondering about this, I do recommend following @FranciscoMatea's advice and referencing [junit's](https://github.com/junit-team/junit5) project structure.